# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, codeigniter

```
<select name='month'> 
    <option value="">Select Month</option> 
    <option value="january" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']=="January")){ echo "selected"; }
    ?>>January</option> 

    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try this, `@if(isset($fetch['bill_month'])) @if($fetch['bill_month'] == "January") selected @endif  @endif`

Comment: NEVER use @ to suppress errors!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You do wrong comparison here. Try to change:

```
<option value="january" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']=="January")){ echo "selected"; }
    ?>>January</option>
```

**to this:**

```
<option value="january" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']) && $fetch['bill_month'] =="January")){ echo "selected"; }
    ?>>January</option>
```

or this short code:

```
<option value="january" <?= (isset($fetch['bill_month']) && $fetch['bill_month'] =="January")) ? "selected" : "" ?>>January</option>
```

Basically `isset($fetch['bill_month'])` return `true` or `false` if the key is set and the value not empty. What you tried to do, is to check if the returned value is equal to some string. My way, you first check if value is present and then if it is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because, `isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error` so you can not pass `expression` to it.

This should work.

```php
<option value="January" 
<?PHP 
$isJan = $fetch['bill_month']=="January";
if(isset($isJan)){ echo "selected"; }
    
?>
>January</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="january" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']=="January")){ echo "selected"; }
```

isset - determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL. So, the condition should be changed into following code:

```
<option value="january" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']) && $fetch['bill_month'] =="January")){ echo "selected"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `isset` is not correct in this situation.

You rather need to do:

```
<option value="january" <?php echo (isset($fetch['bill_month']) && $fetch['bill_month'] =="January")) ? "selected" : "" ?>>January</option>
```

### This should work.

PS:
Considering what you are doing, it will be better to put the months in an array and loop through:

```
<?php
$months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
];
?>

<select name='month'> 
    <option disabled>Select Month</option>
    <?php foreach($months as $month) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo strtolower($month); ?>" <?php if(isset($fetch['bill_month']) && $fetch['bill_month'] == $month) { echo "selected"; }
    ?>>
         <?php echo $month; ?>
    </option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And you won't need to repeat the code for the twelve months.

Also use `Blade` syntax if you are using `Laravel`
Or use PHP own [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)  for `if` and `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
<option value="january" <?php if(NULL !== $fetch['bill_month'] && $fetch['bill_month'] =="January")){ echo "selected"; }
?>>January</option>
```